# android twitter integration with twitter client

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) to integrate my Android app with Twitter. Everything goes smooth, but customer requires to operate through local Twitter client (if installed), not through browser. As you know, integration with Facebook has such a functionality.

I can hardly keep myself from saying that it's impossible... And I want someone to confirm that (or explain how to integrate with client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your solution is correct, but lets look other choices (that you can also explain to your customer):

You could launch an intent to publish some text (your tweet) and let the user handle the client. The problem is that you cannot limit the app to be launched, so the user could choose, for example Facebook, Whatsapp, etc. Taking this choice implies that your share button wouldn't be 'Share via Twitter' or something similar, since you're letting the user to share the text wherever he wants the button should simply say 'Share' (which I think its the best option).

If you don't want to go in that direction, I suggest you to explain your customer (in case you can) that Android have TOO MANY twitter applications, and if the user have more than one you couldn't know which will he use.

I hope this solves your problem (sorry for my bad english).